# Operating system to run WiFi hotspot (only) on Nexus 5 device

Tags: android, linux, networking, mobile

I am looking for a simple operating system, that allows me to start a hotspot and nothing more. My device is a Nexus 5.

The idea behind it is to use it as a hotspot for my laptops. I would rather not use Android because it uses the data plan too. Is there maybe a simple linux that does that job? I am familiar with Debian, Fedora and Manjaro. A very simple clutter free android would be nice too.

Comment: Should your Nexus display anything? If not: run any basic linux on it and set up the access point by connecting via ssh on usb.

Comment: Not displaying anything would be fine, currently I am running Ubuntu Touch. How would I setup the access point with simple linux?